# Is the Lebesgue measure of the $x$ so that this exponential sum is $o(\sqrt{N})$ positive?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums

Consider $$S_N:=\sum_{n=1}^N \exp\left(2\pi i\left(\frac12n^2x+\alpha n\right)\right)$$

where $\alpha$ is irrational. For certain $x$ (say integer) we can get that this is bounded for all $N$. I am curious, for what $x\in \mathbb R$ is this sum "small" - that is $S_N=o(\sqrt N)$?

Is the Lebesgue measure of such $x$ positive?

Comment: Call the sum $S_{N;\alpha}(x)$. Using Chebyshev's inequality, it's straightforward to show that $m(\{x \in [0,2] :|S_{N;\alpha}(x)| \geq C\}) \leq \frac{2N}{C^2}$. Maybe one can do better by considering higher moments?

Comment: A useful keyword is *Weyl sum*, see for example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality_(number_theory)

Comment: This question is partially not well-defined: what is $\alpha$? Do you want the answer as a function of $\alpha$?

Comment: @mathworker21 I would be interested in the answer for any irrational $\alpha$.

Comment: How about almost every?

Comment: @mathworker21 That would certainly be of interest

Comment: Also, I would clarify that "$S_N = o(\sqrt{N})$" is a statement about a given $x$ and means $S_N(x)/\sqrt{N} \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$. One could alternatively ask, for a given (large) $N$, about the Lebesgue measure of the set of $x \in [0,2]$ with $|S_N(x)| \le \frac{\sqrt{N}}{\log\log\log N}$, say.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, apologies if this is overkill, but [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.09306) shows that for almost every (irrational) $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, only a measure $0$ set of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $S_{N,\alpha}(x) = o(\sqrt{N})$ as $N \to \infty$.

Indeed, that paper,

Metric theory of Weyl sums
Changhao Chen, Bryce Kerr, James Maynard, Igor Shparlinski

shows that there is an absolute constant $c > 0$ such that almost every pair $(x,\alpha) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ has $|S_{N,\alpha}(x)| \ge c\sqrt{N}$ for infinitely many $N$. It follows from basic measure theory that for almost every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, it holds for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that $|S_{N,\alpha}(x)| \ge c\sqrt{N}$ for infinitely many $N$.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. I just want to make sure I have this right. Does this imply that for infinitely many $N$, we have that the Lebesgue measure of $x\in [0,1]$ so that $|S_N|/\sqrt N > c$ is $1$?

Comment: @user479223 No, I don't see why it would imply that (apriori).