# Does there exist some irrational $x,\alpha$ so that this Weyl sum is $o(\sqrt N)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums

This is a less ambitious version of [Is the Lebesgue measure of the $x$ so that this exponential sum is $o(\sqrt{N})$ positive?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451975/is-the-lebesgue-measure-of-the-x-so-that-this-exponential-sum-is-o-sqrtn) .

Consider $$S_N(x):=\sum_{n=1}^N \exp\left(2\pi i\left(\frac12n^2x+\alpha n\right)\right)$$

where $\alpha$ is irrational. If $x$ is an integer then $S_N(x)$ is bounded for all $N$. Finding rational $x$ shouldn't be hard either. However, is there some pair $x, \alpha$ of irrational numbers so that $S_N(x)=o(\sqrt N)$?

Comment: It's only less ambitious if it is true, which I'm skeptical of (unless I'm missing something obvious and being stupid).

Comment: If $x,\alpha$ obeyed the claimed asymptotic, then by summation by parts we would have $\vartheta( \alpha; x + i \varepsilon ) = o(\varepsilon^{-1/4})$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$, where $\vartheta$ is the Jacobi theta function.  Given the modularity properties of this function, it seems the equidistribution theory of geodesics on the modular curve may be relevant for this problem, but probably an expert in modular forms and/or homogeneous dynamics would need to be consulted here.

Comment: As it turns out, dynamics is not really needed; modularity suffices.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The estimate
$$ S_N(x) = S_N(x,\alpha) = o(N^{1/2}) \tag {1}$$
cannot hold when $x$ is irrational.

Heuristically, the reason comes from the (approximate) modularity properties of $S_N(x,\alpha)$; this expression is periodic mod $1$ in both $x$ and $\alpha$, and from the [van der Corput B-process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Corput%27s_method) (Poisson summation) one morally has a relation
$$ |S_N(x,\alpha)| 
\sim x^{-1/2} |S_{Nx}( -1/x, \alpha/x)|$$
when $x$ is non-zero (and $Nx$ is not too small).  From periodicity, we see heuristically that if (1) holds for some choice of $x,\alpha,N$, then $x$ (and $\alpha$) can be placed in the interval $[-1/2,1/2]$ while remaining irrational and hence non-zero; from the B-process we may then replace $x,\alpha$ with $-1/x, \alpha/x$ and lower $N$ by a factor of $x$.  Iterating this, we morally arrive at the point where (1) would hold in the range $N \sim 1$, which is absurd because the left-hand side jumps by a unit phase when $N$ increments by $1$, while the right-hand side would now be much less than $1$ due to the $o()$ factor.

To make this argument rigorous we introduce the [Jacobi theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function)
$$ \vartheta(z; \tau) := \sum_{n \in {\bf Z}} e^{\pi i \tau n^2 + 2\pi i z n}$$
defined for complex $z,\tau$ with $\mathrm{Im} \tau > 0$. Morally we have
$$ S_N(x,\alpha) \approx \vartheta( \alpha; x + i N^{-1/2} ).$$
We also will need absolute constants
$$ 0 < \delta \lll \varepsilon_0 \lll \frac{1}{C} \lll 1$$
chosen so that $C$ is sufficiently large, $\varepsilon_0$ is sufficiently small depending on $C$, and $\delta$ is sufficiently small depending on both $C$ and $\varepsilon_0$.  For any $x,\alpha,\varepsilon$ with $0 < \varepsilon < 1/C$, let $P(x,\alpha,\varepsilon)$ denote the assertion that the estimate
$$ |\vartheta(z; \tau)| \leq \delta (\mathrm{Im} \tau)^{-1/4} (1 + C \mathrm{Im}(\tau))$$
holds whenever $z, \tau$ are complex numbers with
\begin{align*}
0 < \mathrm{Im}(\tau) &< \varepsilon\\
|\mathrm{Re}(\tau) - x| &< \mathrm{Im}(\tau) (1 - C \mathrm{Im}(\tau))\\
|\mathrm{Im}(z)| &< \mathrm{Im}(\tau)^{1/2}\\
|\mathrm{Re}(z) - \alpha| &< \mathrm{Im}(\tau)^{1/2} (1 - C \mathrm{Im}(\tau)).
\end{align*}
The $C \mathrm{Im}(\tau)$ terms are technical higher order corrections that we have inserted in order to absorb certain error terms in the iterative component of our analysis, but can be ignored at a first reading.

We then make the following claims:

1. The property $P(x,\alpha,\varepsilon)$ is invariant with respect to shifting $x$ or $\alpha$ by an integer.  This is clear from the periodicity properties of $\vartheta$.
2. If (1) holds for some $x, \alpha$, then $P(x,\alpha,\varepsilon)$ holds for all sufficiently small $\varepsilon > 0$.  This is a routine exercise in summation by parts, splitting
   $ e^{\pi i \tau n^2 + 2\pi i z n}$ into $e^{\pi i x n^2 + 2\pi i \alpha n}$ times a factor which exhibits gaussian decay outside of the region $n = O( (\mathrm{Im} \tau)^{-1/2} )$ and has bounded total variation.
3. If $0 < |x| \leq 1/2$, $|\alpha| \leq 1/2$ and $P(x,\alpha,\varepsilon)$ holds for some $0 < \varepsilon < \varepsilon_0$, then $P(-1/x, \alpha/x, 2\varepsilon)$ holds.  This is a routine computation coming from the Jacobi identity
   $$ \vartheta(z;\tau) = (-i\tau)^{-1/2} e^{-\pi i z^2/\tau} \vartheta(z/\tau;-1/\tau)$$
   which can be viewed as a special case of the Poisson summation formula.
   The main point is that the transformation $(z,\tau) \mapsto (z/\tau, -1/\tau)$ is approximately affine from the region $\tau = -1/x + O(\varepsilon)$, $z = \alpha/x + O(\varepsilon^{1/2})$ to the region $\tau = x + O( \varepsilon x^2 )$, $z = \alpha + O( \varepsilon^{1/2} x)$, up to multiplicative distortion factors of $1 + O( |\tau+1/x|)$ that simplify to $1 - O(\mathrm{Im}(\tau))$ in the region of interest, and which can be tolerated for $C$ large enough.
4. For $\delta$ sufficiently small depending on $\varepsilon_0, C$, it is not possible for $P(x,\alpha,\varepsilon)$ to hold for any $x,\alpha \in [-1/2,1/2]$ if $\varepsilon$ is in the interval $[\varepsilon_0, 2\varepsilon_0]$.  For, if this were possible for arbitrarily small $\delta$, then by sending $\delta$ to zero and using compactness we would see that $\vartheta(z,\tau)$ vanished on an open set, hence vanishes for all $z,\tau$ with $\mathrm{Im}(\tau)> 0$ by analytic continuation, which is absurd.

The four properties 1-4 imply that (1) cannot hold when $x$ is irrational.  Indeed, if (1) was true for some irrational $x,\alpha$, then by property 2 we have $P(x,\alpha,\varepsilon)$ for some $0 < \varepsilon < \varepsilon_0$.  Using property 1 we can shift $x,\alpha$ to lie in $[-1/2,1/2]$, and then by property 3 we can then double $\varepsilon$ (altering $x,\alpha$ again, but keeping $x$ irrational).  Iterating this, we eventually can place $\varepsilon$ in the range $[\varepsilon_0, 2\varepsilon_0]$, at which point we contradict property 4.

This argument actually gives the slightly stronger assertion that
$$ \limsup_{N \to \infty}
N^{-1/2} |\sum_{n \leq N} e^{\pi i x n^2 + 2 \pi i \alpha n}| \geq c$$
for all irrational $x$, real $\alpha$, and some absolute constant $c>0$.